# How can I get OmniSharp VSCode intellisense to work with WSL-compiled code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, omnisharp

When I run `dotnet build` on my code from my WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) distro, C# intellisense breaks and I get errors like the following:

[image]

I've managed to set up the launch configurations found [here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Windows-Subsystem-for-Linux), but that doesn't help with Intellisense, unless I've missed something.

I presume it has something to do with path configurations, but I'm not sure what to change, or where I should change it.

In short, how can I compile and run my code on WSL and edit it in VS Code without errors or warnings?

Comment: is targetDate or valid Dates using YYYY? try lower-cased it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I fell into this question when I looked for this problem I decided to go back to show how I managed to solve it.

To OmniSharp work with WSL i installed the Insiders version of VS Code and the extension `Remote - WSL`.
Done.

Links:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl

OBS: You have to install on your WSL Linux distro the `wget` and `msbuild`

Comment: I do the same last year ... So now APEX brought me back to Windows and i had to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

**There are more possible solutions:**

---

Your folder structure is not correct:

1. Use Terminal in VSCode and create a folder, like `mkdir MyProject`
2. Create your project in the new folder from Terminal, for example: `dotnet new console`

---

Wrong Settings:

Go to:

```
Code -> Preferences -> Settings
```

and remove `"omnisharp.useMono": true/false`

Additionally, you can open your project with Visual Studio or MonoDevelop and then reopen in VSCode.

---

You have wrong input parameters in your `TryParseExact` #LAUGHING

Comment: None of these things are an issue. The project works fine if I restore using Command Prompt.